# authorized download to specific location using Python

Tags: python, authentication, download, mechanize

I am trying to download a file from a website with authentication. I figured out how to download the file, but it will save in the %PROFILE\appdata\local\temp\ directory, with a name like tmpxhq6u1.mobi. How can I save it to another location with another filename?

```
from mechanize import Browser

USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; tr-TR; rv:1.8.1.9) Gecko/20071102 Pardus/2007 Firefox/2.0.0.9"

br = Browser()
br.addheaders = [("User-agent", USER_AGENT)]

br.open("https://login.nrc.nl/login?service=http://digitaleeditie.nrc.nl/digitaleeditie/")

br.select_form(nr=0)
br['username'] = "XXXXXXX"
br['password'] = "xxxxxxx"
# br['rememberMe'] = ["1"]

response = br.submit()
print response.read()
f = br.retrieve('http://digitaleeditie.nrc.nl/digitaleeditie/helekrant/mobipocket/nn_20120521.mobi')[0]
print f
```

Answer (score 1):

The `retrieve` method takes a filename:

```
(filename, headers) = br.retrieve(url, filename)
```

Only if you do not specify the filename does it generate one for you in a temporary directory.

The mechanize `retrieve` method is basically the same as (`urllib.urlretrieve`)[http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve] so you can see how to use `retrieve` by reading the urllib documentation.

Enjoy your newspaper!

Comment: Strange.. I tried this before, and it didn't work. Oh well, works now, thank you! It now downloads the newspaper daily and emails it to my kindle :-)